# Change default Firefox Search URL

Tags: firefox, search, search-engines

NO, I don't want to change my search engine provider (all answers I found were merely on that topic...) - I just want to **adapt** Google's URL **both** for the address bar search and the search widget right of the address bar.

I want to change it to `https://www.google.ch/webhp?tbs=qdr:y&gws_rd=cr`.

**Wait, but why???** Because so, I can limit search results to the **last year** automagically (see `tbs` parameter) - for searching technical stuff on the web it's EXTREMELY ANNOYING that results from 2013 or even older show up first on the result list. Most of that stuff is outdated anyway.

Where does the latest FF (mine is 49 or so) store this information?

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem and here is the best information I can find:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox

There are links at the bottom for automatic XML generators but my browser keeps telling me they're all corrupt. This may be a recent FF 50 update problem, or an I have heavily modified and slightly unstable system problem, let me know if this works for you.